# Do Thunderbolt 3 adapters work on Thunderbolt 4 ports?

Tags: adapter, thunderbolt

I'm waiting for my new laptop to be delivered which has a Thunderbolt 4 port, however I can not figure out if a Thunderbolt 3 to 2 x DisplayPort adapter will work, or any other Thunderbolt 3 to X adapters.

I still haven't gotten an answer from the laptop manufacturer or the shop where I tend to buy my cables from if this will work. Both are of course working under Covid restrictions and have notices on their website that they have a backlog of support questions and deliveries.

So far I have learned that the Thunderbolt 4 standard is a lot stricter on which features are required but not sure if that means that a Thunderbolt 3 adapter will always work on Thunderbolt 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Thunderbolt 4 ports and cables are all backwards compatible with thunderbolt 3. However you will not be able to reach the Thunderbolt 4 supported resolutions and speeds with a thunderbolt 3 cable. Your device will act as if you used a Thunderbolt 3 port.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know that I can order a Thunderbolt3 adapter as long as it supports the resolutions I need